# Jenkins for Production deployment

Tags: jenkins

This question is just arising out of curiosity. Everyone now a days use jenkins for build and deployment automation, but still many of these people shy away from using the jenkins for Production deployment.

Considering Jenkins is such a nice and easy tool, I don't really understand why we don't see more of Jenkins in production deployment. Is it because of some security reasons? If yes, what these security reasons might be?

Or any other reason which exists that make some people to have 2 different tools for automation, one for dev and lower environment and another for higher environment like production.

Answer (score 0):

System Admins running Production environments don't want to be obsoleted/automated out of their job by "Dev tools"

Comment: There are still many companies/clients favoring the automation of production deployment, but they are not using jenkins.. even though there low level environments use jenkins..

Comment: Like I said, low level environment are usually managed by the Devs themselves and with Jenkins being the Dev tool for build and CI, Dev continue to use it for deployment. The production environments are managed by production System Admins teams, and since they are not Dev, they don't use Jenkins for other day-to-day tasks, so it's foreign and unknown to them. They use tools that **they** are familiar with and have full control over. And let's face it Jenkins doesn't provide any kind of "Deployment and monitoring" out of the box. You only get it with lots of configuration and plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I might be bit late here but I would like to share an automated process that will allow you to handle the entire production Deployment using a single YAML file.

**For more information**
https://github.com/frostyaxe/Blaze-Tracker